# Submit a form with anchor (<a>) tag with some value in ASP.Net MVC using Html.BeginFrom

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Html.BeginFrom ... to create a from Tag and Submit request to use external login providers.

**The HttpPost action in Account Controller**

```
//
// POST: /Account/ExternalLogin

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

I need to send the RetunUrl and the Provider to the above action method
Currently i am creating Multiple forms using a `Foreach` with `Razor`

```
@foreach (ExternalLoginViewModel loginViewModel in Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { Provider = loginViewModel.AuthenticationClientData.DisplayName, ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a class="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssStyle" href="#">
            <div class="@loginViewModel.DivCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.DivCssStyle">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="@loginViewModel.IconCssClass"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    }
}
```

But i think it can be done using a single from but i dont know how i can provide the `Provider` value which varies with the anchorTag Something like :

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { Provider = "<SomeValue>", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @foreach (ExternalLoginViewModel loginViewModel in Model)
        {
             <a class="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssStyle" href="#">
                <div class="@loginViewModel.DivCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.DivCssStyle">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="@loginViewModel.IconCssClass"></span>
                 </div>
            </a>
        }

 }
```

**Javascript used in the earlier case is (it works fine)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".CSSclassonAnchor", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).closest("form");
            form.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think its somehow will be posssible to post data using an anchor Tag 
Any help in this regard will be great.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is adding a hidden field to the form, and populate it from javascript. In your view modify the BeginForm to no include Provider parameter and add a `<input type="hidden" />` in the form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("Provider", "", new {id=hdnprovider})
    @foreach (ExternalLoginViewModel loginViewModel in Model)
    {
         <a class="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.AnchorCssStyle" href="#" data-name="@loginViewModel.AuthenticationClientData.DisplayName">
            <div class="@loginViewModel.DivCssClass" style="@loginViewModel.DivCssStyle">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="@loginViewModel.IconCssClass"></span>
             </div>
        </a>
    }
 }
```

Then in Javascript use the data-name attribute of the link clicked and assign it to the hidden:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-name]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        $("#hdnprovider").val($(this).data("Name"));
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

As the hidden has the name "Provider" it will be automatically binded to "Provider" parameter in your controller.